# Button not getting displayed in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've written a code for frontend Facebook login with Django-rest in the backend for verification. But, the button attribute in my HTML file is not getting displayed
Here is the code to my file(HTML) in AngularJS

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root">
</div>

<script>  
    //facebook here
    //***************************************************
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({
     appId      : 'Not inserted app id here for security reasons',
     status     : true,
     xfbml      : true
        });
    };
    
    (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</ script>

<button ng-click="login_fb()">Login with facebook</button>
<script> 
angular.module("myApp").controller("UserCtrl", 
 ['$scope','$location', 'Facebook',
        function($scope, $location, Facebook /*we will write this factory next*/){
        
        $scope.login_fb = function(){
           Facebook.login().then(function(response){
               //this is where we'll contact backend. for now just log response 
               console.log(response);
           });
        }
}]);
</ script>
<script>
angular.module("myApp").factory('Facebook', 
    ["$q", "$window", "$rootScope",
    function($q, $window, $rootScope) {
   
 // since we are resolving a thirdparty response, 
        // we need to do so in $apply   
 var resolve = function(errval, retval, deferred) {
     $rootScope.$apply(function() {
         if (errval) {
      deferred.reject(errval);
         } else {
      retval.connected = true;
             deferred.resolve(retval);
         }
     });
        }

 var _login = function(){
     var deferred = $q.defer();
            //first check if we already have logged in
     FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
         if (response.status === 'connected') {
             // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
      // app
      console.log("fb user already logged in");
      deferred.resolve(response);
  } else {
      // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
      // but has not authenticated your app
      FB.login(function(response){
          if(response.authResponse){
       console.log("fb user logged in");
       resolve(null, response, deferred);
   }else{
       console.log("fb user could not log in");
       resolve(response.error, null, deferred);
   }
      });
   }
      });
   
      return deferred.promise;
 }

 return{
  login: _login,
 };
}]);
</ script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anbody please tell me why my button not getting displayed.

Comment: and what exactly does `the button attribute` even mean? Please explain things in more precise terms and explain what is expected to happen, when or how it should happen and what is currently happening. this is just not the proper way to ask a uestion

Comment: I'll keep that in mind from the next time. For now, my problem is sorted though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`</ script>` is not a valid HTML tag. Change these to `</script>`.

Comment: Right, there are 3 closing script tags incorrectly written: